# How to merge this three column, in google sheet into only one ya?

Tags: excel-formula, spreadsheet

Need your kind help to merge this column (A,B,C) into one column (on column D) using Google Sheet.
also I want to show updated automatically, if I add new data.

[TABLE WITH 3 COLUMN DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op1Af.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you can use
`=join(" ";A2:C2)` on `D2` cell

Answer (score 0):

Just add formula `=JOIN(" ",A1:C1)`

[image: OUTPUT]

```
JOIN(delimiter, value_or_array1, [value_or_array2, …])
```